# TFS - Automaticlly added to the wrong TFS project

Tags: tfs

Some time ago I accidentally created an Visual Studio project and selected the option "Add to source control" and use my project root dir "c:\users\foobar\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects". But I never check this project into the TFS. The name of this project was "Foobar_Standalone".

It was in my "Source Control Explorer" and the mapping was set to "c:\users\foobar\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects". I removed this via "Undo pending changes" (the option "Advanced > Remove Mapping" was disabled).

Today whenever I crate a new visual-studio project and select this option "Add to source control" and locate the project in "c:\users\foobar\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects" is this project added to the "Foobar_Standalone" folder in the "Source Control Explorer".

So from my understanding remembers TFS that there was a mapping for "Foobar_Standalone" with the local path "c:\users\foobar\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects", but how do I remove this mapping for good?

Comment: As always I just found the solution minutes after I created the SO question, sorry. In case you have the same problem: 1 In the "Source Control Explorer" go to "Workspaces…"; 2. In the next dialog select the workspace and hit "Edit"; 3. Remove the wrong mapping

Comment: Please transform your comment in an answer and approve it, so the question is marked answered.

Answer (score 0):

As always I just found the solution minutes after I created the SO question, sorry. In case you have the same problem:

1. In the "Source Control Explorer" go to "Workspaces…";
2. In the next dialog select the workspace and hit "Edit";
3. Remove the wrong mapping